# How do I make a bar graph with labels and counts?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I realize this is a simple question, but I’m having trouble getting this graph to display right.

I have a dataset like:

| pet | pet_counts |
| --- | --- |
| dog | 22 |
| cat | 100 |
| birs | 2 |

I want to make a bar graph that has the X-Axis labeled with each animal and the counts along the Y. When I specify, labs it just changed the words in the label but not the value below the tick marks.

I want the x axis to say dog and then in the Y have a count for f 22, for example.

I have tried:

```
Graph <- ggplot(data = animals, aes(pet_counts)) + geom_bar(stat=“count”) + labs(x = “pet”)
```

Comment: `ggplot(data = animals, aes(x = pet, y = pet_counts)) + geom_col()`

Comment: Wow, thank you! If you want to put that as an answer, I’ll be more than happy to select it. I don’t think I can select comments. Thanks again

Comment: Also try `barplot(animals$pet_counts, names.arg=animals$pet)`.

Comment: Just the code is not a great answer, jpiversen's explanation is much higher quality and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

animals <- tibble(
  pet = c("dog", "cat", "birds"),
  pet_counts = c(22, 100, 2)
)

animals %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = pet, y = pet_counts)) + 
  geom_col() +
  labs(
    x = "Pet",
    y = "Count"
  )
```

The `labs()` function is optional, and will just change the names on the axis to something more readable.

The result:

[image: Final plot]

The difference between `geom_col()` and `geom_bar()`, according to the documentation:

> `geom_bar()` makes the height of the bar proportional to the number of cases in each group. If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data, use `geom_col()` instead.

Since you already have `pet_counts`, you should use `geom_col()`.

Comment: to clarify, `geom_col` is nothing else than a short hand (wrapper) around geom_bar(stat = "identity")

Comment: True, good clarification